# get url of facebook video to download it?

Tags: php, image, facebook, video, download

How can I get the download URL video of Facebook without need to be logged in?

For example : 
This a normal Facebook's video : 
https://www.facebook.com/Itscrafttime.kelinetwork/videos/264095734229487/

I used this website to get the downloading link
https://www.fbdown.net/download.php

Download link: 
https://video-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/41135775_328269491258234_6544430827864850432_n.mp4?_nc_cat=1&efg=eyJybHIiOjQ3NSwicmxhIjo5MTUsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic3ZlX3NkIn0%3D&rl=475&vabr=264&oh=728c4e7ff8bb02461309c18a626a9c21&oe=5BB3E06D

Is there any way to get this link by using my PHP?

I tried to download the page, Then search for ".mp4" or video id , but without any successes.

Thank you..